# How can i fix InvalidOperationException on BeginGetRequestStream?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method i'm using to upload a file to ftp:

```
public FtpUploader()
        {
            try
            {
                State state = new State();
                state.request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
                   ftpurl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
                state.request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                state.request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
                state.sourceStream = new StreamReader(filename);
                state.request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), state);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                state.fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(state.sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                state.sourceStream.Close();

                Send(state);
                sendDone.WaitOne();
                state.requestStream.Close();

                Receive(state);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();

                Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", state.stringResponse);

                state.response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string t = err.ToString();
            }
        }
```

When it's getting to the line:

```
Send(state);
```

Then it's jumping to the Send method and trying to do the line inside:

```
private static void Send(State state)
        {
            state.request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
        }
```

When it's trying to do this line it's jumping back to the FtpUploader method to the catch area and throw the exception:

InvalidOperationException:

Cannot re-call BeginGetRequestStream/BeginGetResponse while a previous call is still in progress

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Cannot re-call BeginGetRequestStream/BeginGetResponse while a previous call is still in progress.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at mws.FtpUploader.Send(State state) in FtpUploader.cs:line 151
       at mws.FtpUploader..ctor() in FtpUploader.cs:line 63
  InnerException:
```

Line 151 is:

```
state.request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
```

And Line 63 is:

```
Send(state);
```

Comment: It seems that you did not finish the first async operation `state.request.BeginGetRequestStream(...)`. Use corresponding EndGetRequestStream method.

Comment: Are you aware that using an async IO method and immediately waiting for completion is not only useless but harmful for performance?

Comment: You can check if the state is final or not. private static void Send(State state)
        {
            if(state.IsFinal)  
            state.request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
        }

Comment: usr no could you show me how to make it right ?

Comment: Use synchronous IO. Also, understand what async IO is actually for.